# assistance in finding pattern in if statements containing modulus operator

Tags: javascript, function, modulus

I am working in a personal project and I found myself repeating a lot of code:

```
// this code is in a function with params k & dir

// where i equals a number from 0-2 inclusive
// j = (i + 1) % 2
// k = (j + 1) % 2
// The objective is to change a.x, a.y, b.x, & b.y



1.  if(k === 0 && dir === -1) { a.x = dir *  array[k].x; a.y = dir * array[k].y; b.x = dir * -array[i].x; b.y = dir * -array[i].y; }
2.  if(k === 0 && dir ===  1) { a.x = dir *  array[i].x; a.y = dir * array[i].y; b.x = dir * -array[k].x; b.y = dir * -array[k].y; }
3.
4.  if(k === 1 && dir === -1) { a.x = dir * -array[i].x; a.y = dir * array[i].y; b.x = dir * -array[i].x; b.y = dir * -array[i].y; }
5.  if(k === 1 && dir ===  1) { a.x = dir * -array[i].x; a.y = dir * array[i].y; b.x = dir * -array[i].x; b.y = dir * -array[i].y; }
6.  
7.  if(k === 2 && dir === -1) { a.x = dir * -array[j].x; a.y = dir * array[j].y; b.x = dir *  array[i].x; b.y = dir * -array[i].y; }
8.  if(k === 2 && dir ===  1) { a.x = dir * -array[i].x; a.y = dir * array[i].y; b.x = dir *  array[j].x; b.y = dir * -array[j].y; }
```

I've been trying to reduce the code for two days without any luck, and I frankly believe that there must be a way to not use all of those if statements.

I simply want a stir in the right direction, although a complete solution would be very much welcome.

Up until now I tried doing things like using the modulus operator again, but the problem comes with parts like line `7` & `8`, because the array indexes are different depending on whether your object is `a` or `b`. So I believe there must be at least two if statements, but I am simply lost.

Again, more than anything this is becoming a puzzle, so I hope it is at least fun for you coding experts :)

## Edit

The code already works, it is simply repeated and I was hoping to find a more concise solution. All values are numbers, `a` and `b` are both objects that contain `{ x: undefined, y: undefined }`.

Separated into both objects for the sake of clarity:

```
    // for a
    if(k === 0 && dir === -1) { a.x = dir *  array[k].x; a.y = dir *  array[k].y; } // (0, -1) => (0)
    if(k === 0 && dir ===  1) { a.x = dir *  array[i].x; a.y = dir *  array[i].y; } // (0,  1) => (1)

    if(k === 1 && dir === -1) { a.x = dir * -array[i].x; a.y = dir *  array[i].y; } // (1, -1) => (2)
    if(k === 1 && dir ===  1) { a.x = dir * -array[i].x; a.y = dir *  array[i].y; } // (1,  1) => (2)

    if(k === 2 && dir === -1) { a.x = dir * -array[j].x; a.y = dir *  array[j].y; } // (2, -1) => (1)
    if(k === 2 && dir ===  1) { a.x = dir * -array[i].x; a.y = dir *  array[i].y; } // (2,  1) => (0)


    // for b
    if(k === 0 && dir === -1) { b.x = dir * -array[i].x; b.y = dir * -array[i].y; } // (0, -1) => (1)
    if(k === 0 && dir ===  1) { b.x = dir * -array[k].x; b.y = dir * -array[k].y; } // (0,  1) => (0)

    if(k === 1 && dir === -1) { b.x = dir * -array[i].x; b.y = dir * -array[i].y; } // (1, -1) => (2)
    if(k === 1 && dir ===  1) { b.x = dir * -array[i].x; b.y = dir * -array[i].y; } // (1,  1) => (2)

    if(k === 2 && dir === -1) { b.x = dir *  array[i].x; b.y = dir * -array[i].y; } // (2, -1) => (0)
    if(k === 2 && dir ===  1) { b.x = dir *  array[j].x; b.y = dir * -array[j].y; } // (2,  1) => (1)
```

The comments at the end of each line show input => output, where `(k, dir) => output`, and the output value is the index given to `array`.

`array` is an array outside of the scope of the function.

## Edit2

```
    for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        // list has arrays inside containing coordinates in a 2d plane, following a triangular grid. Each value looks like this [0, 2, -1]
        // j = next modulus value in base 3 given i
        // k = next modulus value in base 3 given j
        let j = (i + 1) % 3;
        let k = (i + 2) % 3;

        list[i] = [...old_list].sort((a, b) => { // sort list
            // This provides 3 sorted lists which are sorted by xy, yz, and zx
            if(a[i] === b[i]) {
                if( a[j] === b[j] && Math.abs(a[k] - b[k]) ) {
                    my_function(a, b, i, j, k);
                }
                return a[j] - b[j];
            }
            return a[i] - b[i];
        });
    }

    my_function(a, b, i, j, k) {
        let modules = universe.modules;
        let dir = b[k] - a[k];

        a = {x: undefined, y: undefined};
        b = {x: undefined, y: undefined};

        if(k === 0 && dir === -1) { a.x = dir *  module.constraints[k].x; a.y = dir *  module.constraints[k].y; } // (0, -1) => (0)
        if(k === 0 && dir ===  1) { a.x = dir *  module.constraints[i].x; a.y = dir *  module.constraints[i].y; } // (0,  1) => (1)

        if(k === 1 && dir === -1) { a.x = dir * -module.constraints[i].x; a.y = dir *  module.constraints[i].y; } // (1, -1) => (2)
        if(k === 1 && dir ===  1) { a.x = dir * -module.constraints[i].x; a.y = dir *  module.constraints[i].y; } // (1,  1) => (2)

        if(k === 2 && dir === -1) { a.x = dir * -module.constraints[j].x; a.y = dir *  module.constraints[j].y; } // (2, -1) => (1)
        if(k === 2 && dir ===  1) { a.x = dir * -module.constraints[i].x; a.y = dir *  module.constraints[i].y; } // (2,  1) => (0)



        if(k === 0 && dir === -1) { b.x = dir * -module.constraints[i].x; b.y = dir * -module.constraints[i].y; } // (0, -1) => (1)
        if(k === 0 && dir ===  1) { b.x = dir * -module.constraints[k].x; b.y = dir * -module.constraints[k].y; } // (0,  1) => (0)

        if(k === 1 && dir === -1) { b.x = dir * -module.constraints[i].x; b.y = dir * -module.constraints[i].y; } // (1, -1) => (2)
        if(k === 1 && dir ===  1) { b.x = dir * -module.constraints[i].x; b.y = dir * -module.constraints[i].y; } // (1,  1) => (2)

        if(k === 2 && dir === -1) { b.x = dir *  module.constraints[i].x; b.y = dir * -module.constraints[i].y; } // (2, -1) => (0)
        if(k === 2 && dir ===  1) { b.x = dir *  module.constraints[j].x; b.y = dir * -module.constraints[j].y; } // (2,  1) => (1)

        // doing some stuff with Matter.js(physics library) to decide where to add constraints between two bodies
    }
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? What is a and b? What is i, j, k? What is dir? What is an example input, and expected output?

Comment: Are the parameters `k & dir` as written or `i & dir`, which seems to make more sense based on the logic?

Comment: @MattWay I've now included more information, more than that would transcend the scope of the question, I believe. *Edit* Had a mistake, now it's fixed.

Comment: @ScottSauyet, no, `k & dir` are the parameters, the reason why I don't use `i` instead is so because this function is called by another function, and for the sake of clarity in the other function, `k` is the value given

Comment: So then what does this mean?:  "where i equals a number from 0-2 inclusive", where `j` is then defined in terms of it and `k` is **re**defined in terms of `j`?  That seems very odd.

Comment: @ScottSauyet, yeah, sorry :P that's because the previous function has this
 let j = (i + 1) % 3;
 let k = (i + 2) % 3;
 
 new_list[i] = [...old_list].sort((a, b) => {
  if(a[i] === b[i]) {
   if( a[j] === b[j] && Math.abs(a[k] - b[k]) ) {
    this_function()
   }
  }
 }

The whole thing is wrapped in a for loop that goes from 0-2 inclusive

Comment: I'm afraid, though, that it's not clear what the new rules are.  `i` doesn't seem to be defined, and therefore `j` isn't either, and `k` is circular at best.

Comment: @JaackoTorus You are misunderstanding my request. You have given us some arbitrary code, and asked if we can make it simpler. This is difficult, because as humans we have to attempt to figure out your true intention, and then form a simpler program. It would be much easier if you were to just give us your intention, instead of the above. For example, you might say i'm trying to find the x of two vectors. In other words, what do all your variables represent, and what is their purpose?

Comment: @ScottSauyet Sorry I tried formatting the code but it doesn't work on comments :( but I hope it now makes sense why I pass `k`, it's purely more for how the previous function looks. And I could pass i as well, but I'm comparing the third value since I'm ordering arrays, I would simply redefine `k`, because at the end of the day what I am truly comparing is `k` not `i`. Thank you so much for taking the time to help :)

Comment: @MattWay I understand, the reasoning of why I want to this has to do with trying to get a directional vector in a triangular plane, but what I'm trying to accomplish is find the difference in x, y, or z given that all other coordinates are equal in an array with many different `x, y, and z` and find whether the sorting algorithm is going backwards or forwards in the axis in which is sorting. I've provided how the part that I'm talking about works for a better context.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I've provided the for loop that calls the function for further context.

Comment: I updated my original answer idea to move closer to this updated API.  I'm not sure how close it is, but it may be enough to get you moving, anyway.  For me, bedtime.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably something wrong with this code.  The question has changed since I started writing it, and I probably haven't kept up.  But I think this might at least show a technique to avoid the repetition:

```js
const rules = [[0, -1, 'k', 'k', 'i', 'i'], [0, 1, 'i', 'i', 'k', 'k'], /* ... */]

const foo = (i, j, k, dir, array) => {
    const idxs = {i, j, k}
    const a = {}, b = {}
    const [,, ax, ay, bx, by] = rules.find(([rk, rd, ..._]) => rk === k && rd === dir)
    a.x = dir *  array[idxs[ax]].x
    a.y = dir *  array[idxs[ay]].y
    b.x = dir * -array[idxs[bx]].x 
    b.y = dir * -array[idxs[by]].y
    return {a, b}
}

console.log(foo(0, 1, 0, -1, [{x: 1, y: 2}]))
```

The important part is the list of rules, which actually capture your logic, and the `idxs` object which allows for a translation of those to actual values.  There might be a way to carry this further, doing something similar with the a's, b's, x's and y's.  But I think this strikes a readability balance.

Comment: I upvoted just for attempting an answer to this bizarre question.This seems like a good candidate for some obfuscated code competition. Sorry OP, I know dealing with Physics can be hard, but I guess naming variables sensibly will go a long way in getting more answers.

Comment: Also upvoted for the shear attempt. I just feel like this is something where the simplicity would be elsewhere is the right question was asked.

Comment: I guess I simply didn't find the code that complex, mostly just repetitive.  And all I tried to do was to simplify the repetition.  The only complexity I noted was in the confusion between `k` and `i`.  This version simply punts on that issue.